# UDF to evaluate a text string which represents a formula

Tags: vba, excel, user-defined-functions

This seems like a very simple problem, but  I simply lack the knowledge to answer, and can't find an answer when googling.

As far as I understand, when you type a formula in a cell in Excel, like `=SUM(B1:B3)`, you are entering a text string. Pressing the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key evaluates this text string by letting Excel know it's a formula.

In my case I do not type the text string, it is generated in a cell as follows:

- `A1` contains `'=SUM(x:y)` *(note the **'**, i.e. as text)*
- `A2` contains `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"x","B1"),"y","B3")`

  - That returns in `A2`, `=SUM(B1:B3)` *as a text string*

I would like a UDF like '`EVALUATE()`' in `A3` which has the same effect as typing the function in `A3` and pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>↵</kbd> key.

- `A3` contains `=EVALUATE(A2)` which is the same as `=EVALUATE("=SUM(B1:B3)")`

  - *(perhaps no `=` sign within the SUM)*
- `A3` then returns the output of the formula that was stored as text, exactly the same as if you had typed `=SUM(B1:B3)` into it directly

---

I realise at this stage it's customary to give example/ attempted code. Unfortunately my lack of knowledge is in the area which is fundamental to solving the problem, so I fear my code has little to offer. I post it anyway, or at least a skeleton:

```
Sub EVALUATE_Test() 'a temporary macro to run the EVALUATE function with an input text of "B1^2"
Debug.Print EVALUATE("B1^2")
End Sub

Function EVALUATE(InputFormula As String) 'defining the UDF and Input - I'm not sure how to dimension evaluate though, as it could output text or a number

'here is where the code goes to evaluate the InputFormula

EVALUATE = InputFormula & "hi" 'Obviously the real UDF won't need '& "hi" but I put it in to test the debugging!
End Function
```

I hope that's enough to go on, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you aware of the built-in Evaluate function? That should be involved in your thinking... `Application.Evaluate(inputFormula)`, I would think, once you remove the '=', then most things might be solved.

Comment: You don't even need to remove the '= sign.

Comment: didn't even know that Rory :-). Op, this question will be easily solved if you just use Evaluate...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this UDF, and see how it works. May need small tweaking, but this is the core of what you need.

```
Public Function eval(ByVal str As String) As Variant
  eval = Application.Evaluate(str)
End Function
```

Comment: I know this won't work for some functions, like `EVAL("HYPERLINK(""https://www.google.com"")")` doesn't give you a link, but at least it doesn't throw an error! I can see there's some tweaking to be done for those functions which VBA has its own versions of, but thanks for the starting point!